# aspnet-codegeneration segmentation fault

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I happen to follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli), using dotnet CLI. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04. After running `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -fi Account.Register -dc WebPWrecover.Models.WebPWrecoverContext`, nothing happens. If I try to run `~/.dotnet/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`,  only get `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally sort of figured it out. The issue was happening with all dotnet tools, `fake` being the most recent one. So I stumbled upon [this seemingly unrelated github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/973), which at least contained segfault with `dotnet new`.

I tried all the diagnostic steps there, the most important ones:

1. `export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1` - no effect
2. `strace -f -o logfile-codegenerator ~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` - All dotnet tools crashed after line `arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fee92b0d740) = 0`. Don't know what to make of it.
3. `gdb --args  ~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`. GDB tool gave me I think 3 lines of addresses, not a single mention of calling any other lib (apart to what github issue mentions)

So this lead me to think that the problem lies within my installation of dotnet, since the program crashed upon it's very start.

Important to mention, I installed the dotnet SDK via snapcraft. After uninstalling it and [installing the dotnet SDK normally](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-current) and installing some dotnet tools afterwards (`testingdotnettuls dotnet tool install fake-cli -g`), I can confirm that dotnet tools work again.

So, long story short, if you use snap version of dotnet SDK and face unexpected segfaults, install via apt.